# Painleve's theorem on removable singularities for compact subsets of zero length

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

I have this problem:
[image: page1]

The exercise mentioned in the above problem is here:
[image: page2]

How do I prove this using the given hint? The question I have is if I consider a portion of S and cover it with connected disks, they are no longer disjoint and I cant use the given exercise. I am confused about what limit I need to take.

Comment: Following the hint you're provided, if you group together the overlapping disks, you end up with regions whose interiors are disjoint.  For the limit, it presumably means to take $\epsilon \to 0$ to show that the second sum in the expression for $f(z_0)$ in Exercise 2 vanishes.

Comment: @JHF -Thank you. I have a question - why does the hypothesis state that these disks should be connected?  How does that help me?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you're asking why you need to group the disks into connected components for Exercise 3, it's precisely so that you can apply Exercise 2, as you've identified.

Comment: @JHF. if the radii go to zero, i,e $\epsilon \to 0$ in the second sum in the expression for $z_0$, $z-z_0 \to 0$ therefore this term should to to $\infty$? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having an extended discussion in the comments, let me provide an answer.

As in the hint, we work locally in some disk which we shall also call $U$ with boundary given by the contour $\gamma_0$, oriented counterclockwise.  We want to show that for all $z_0 \in U \setminus S$, $$f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_0} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} \, dz,$$ so that $$h(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_0} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} \, dz, \quad \forall z_0 \in U$$ is an analytic continuation of $f$ from $U \setminus S$ to $U$.

Fix $z_0 \in U \setminus S$.  Since $S$ is compact, we have $d := d(z_0,S) > 0$.  Let $0 < \epsilon < \frac{d}{3}$.  By hypothesis $S$ can be covered by balls $\{B_1, \ldots, B_n\}$ whose radii sum to $< \epsilon$, and without loss of generality we suppose that each ball intersects $S$ in a nonempty set.  Therefore, we have $d(z_0, \bigcup_n B_n) > \frac{d}{3}$.

Group the balls by connected component, and let $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_m$ be the boundary of each connected component, oriented counterclockwise.  In other words, $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_m$ are disjoint contours with disjoint interiors such that $\partial(\bigcup_n B_n) = \bigcup_j \gamma_j$.  (Some minor modifications may be needed to achieve this.)

By Exercise 2, we have $$f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_0} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} \, dz - \sum_j \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_j} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} \, dz,$$ so
$$\begin{align}
\left\lvert f(z_0) - \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_0} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} \, dz \right\rvert &= \left\lvert \sum_j \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_j} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} \, dz \right\rvert \\
&\leq \sum_j \frac{1}{2\pi} (\operatorname{length}(\gamma_j) \cdot \sup_{z \in \gamma_j} \left\lvert \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\right\rvert)
\end{align}$$

We can see that $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_j \operatorname{length}(\gamma_j) \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_n \operatorname{length}(\partial B_n) < \epsilon.$$  Moreover, since $f$ is bounded on $U \setminus S$, say $\left\lvert f(z) \right\rvert \leq M$, we have $$\left\lvert \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} \right\rvert \leq \frac{M}{d(z_0, \bigcup_j \gamma_j)} \leq \frac{M}{d/3}$$ whenever $z \in \bigcup_j \gamma_j$.  Hence, $$\left\lvert f(z_0) - \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_0} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} \, dz \right\rvert < \frac{3M\epsilon}{d}.$$

Taking the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, we get $$f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_0} \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0} \, dz$$ as desired, and this holds for all $z_0 \in U \setminus S$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @JHF.